# Сведения об авторизации пользователей ОС семейства Linux

Tags: python, linux, база-данных, авторизация, логирование

Мне необходимо создать БД для хранения сведений об авторизации пользователей ОС семейства Linux. И вот я не могу понять каким образом я могу эти сведения передать в качестве входных данных в свою программу. Парсить файл auth.log не вариант. Так как в новых версиях линукса файл просто отсутствует и всё сведения можно просмотреть лишь через journalctl. Было предложение воспользоваться [osquery](https://osquery.io/schema/5.11.0/#iptables). Но почитав документацию не нашел ничего (практически) связанного с авторизацией. Также предложение воспользоваться модулем PAM, но я что-то вообще не понял как я могу с его помощью получить сведения и передать их входными данными в программу. Нужна помощь в передаче данных авторизации в мою программу

Comment: Что-то мешает парсить journalctl?

Comment: это консольная команда, которая выводит информацию в консоль, а как мне внутри программы, вызвать journalctl, так еще и считать данные из консоли на python

Comment: @ЗахарКутьин а если вывод команды направить в файл?

Comment: Ну во-первых, можно тупо запихнуть journactl в [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), а во-вторых, systemd предоставляет Python-модуль для работы с собой https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html#accessing-the-journal (и примеры кода можно подглядеть например тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331116)

Comment: как вариант, насколько я помню такое возможно. Но тогда вопрос другой, каким образом передать при выполнении программы на python вызов команды journalctl

Comment: @andreymal а вот это прекрасный совет, нужно опробовать, ну я думаю это может стать решением. Спасибо

Comment: (но вообще с точки зрения здравого смысла PAM выглядит наиболее логичным решением, но я сам с ним работать не умею, но может в вопрос заглянет кто-нибудь кто умеет)

Comment: @andreymal Pam довольно тонкая штука. Я бы не стал туда соваться без крайней необходимости. Но думаю завтра дополню свой ответ ради спортивного интереса.)

Answer (score 0):

Вот например есть модуль готовый `pam_pgsql`. Его повесить на хук session и добавить запрос. Будет писать в базу все входы и выходы.

Comment: то есть я в него могу пописать команду на отправку мне данных сразу в БД?

Comment: Да, только конфиг правильно сделать